# Proper ProxyPassReverse with rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm trying to do something similar to the Coral cache.
For example if a client/browser looks up google.com.foo.com, it gets passed to a proxy by apache and serves a proxied/cached version of google.com to the client/browser.

My configuration for this so far is this:

```
ProxyRemote * http://localhost:8080
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.*)\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [P]
```

This actually works well as long as the website does not redirect to another site, but as soon as it redirects, it "bursts" out of the proxy and simply goes to the redirected site (oviously).

ProxyPassReverse should, as far as I understand it, prevent this, but I simply can't piece together how my ProxyPassReverse directive should look. After all, the hostname could be everything in this case...
Is this even possible?